# DataFusion -HTTP Post Callback Action

Tags: http, google-cloud-data-fusion, cdap

I have a pipeline alert set to make a http post call on completion of the pipeline.
I need to push a file from GCS bucket to the end point url.
Can someone help me how can I achieve this?

Comment: you want to push the object when making the post call? or in a different request?

Comment: yes wanted to push a file from GCS bucket to the http post endpoint url.

Answer (score 0):

For this you can create a Cloud Function [1], and have the code that sends the desired file to the desired endpoint another endpoint.

You could use this code a code sample [2] and modify the last lines instead of downloading the file send it to and endpoint.

I hope this helps, if this solution doesn't suit you are you have more questions just ask and provide a some more context please.

[1] https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/http
[2] https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/downloading-objects#code-samples

Comment: To extend to this answer to clarify how to use this, to trigger the HTTP trigger in [1] using any of the methods shown there, it would be a good idea to send an HTTP request in the final step of the Data Fusion pipeline.